# How to restart the pods even if there no change to the config

Tags: kubernetes, containers

I build docker images on one server and then load it onto to the nodes(using docker save and docker load cmds).

Then I make change to the dep_config file to pull it locally instead of repo.(by setting imagepullpolicy).

After that step I do "kubectl apply -f dep_config.yml".

Now, the pod restarts only for the 1st time but subsequent load of images and apply of config file, the pods dont restart.

Is there way I can restart the pod with "kubectl apply" even if there is no change in the config_deploy.yml file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A common practice is to change a non-used label of the deployment using the `patch` command

```
kubectl patch deployment your-deployment -p \ 
"{\"spec\":{\"template\":{\"metadata\":{\"labels\":{\"date\":\"$(date +%s)\"}}}}}"
```

Basically you can change anything that's inside the pod template, even things, like in this example, that no one notices.

Comment: This is definitely the best workaround currently available, one small thing to keep in mind though when using `labels`, as per the k8s documentation, "Labels can be used to select objects and to find collections of objects that satisfy certain conditions. In contrast, annotations are not used to identify and select objects." So `labels` could lead to unintended selection results, whereas `annotations` are completely safe.

Comment: Do annotation changes actually roll out new pods? Or do only certain changes within the Deployment cause a new deployment rollout?